# Which Namespace used to Convert Byte[] array to Image in asp.net core C#?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I convert byte array into Image using asp.net C#? First time I convert Image to byte array and stored in the database. Now I want to show it in DataTable called by Ajax. Now I'm trying to convert this way. But the Image type is missing.

**Which namespace need to use**

```
 public Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] bytesArr)
        {
            using (MemoryStream memstr = new MemoryStream(bytesArr))
            {
                Image img = Image.FromStream(memstr);
                return img;
            }
        }
```

Comment: It should be `System.Drawing;`,

Comment: It's not working.  I'm trying to use that.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Isn't it convenient to convert it into `base64` since your ultimate plan is to bind it in `client side`

Answer (score 0):

[Image.FromStream -> System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=windowsdesktop-7.0)

[Memorystream -> System.Io](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-6.0)